# How do you center two texts in containers inside a row widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-container, flutter-row

How do you center two texts in containers inside a row widget?

[image] 
 [image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits. Also please provide more details about what you've done and want you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Center widget and put

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
...)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I did what you told me to do and nothing has changed.

Comment: Instead of `mainAxisAlignment`, try `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`